# Trouble with Aquaterm on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I was working on a project in Octave with GNUPlot, and had no trouble with Aquaterm until i recently installed some software updates. Aquaterm has suddenly stopped working altogether and i can't figure out why!!!
GNUPlot is working fine. the command >plot sin(x) gives no error, however aqua term does not start on execution like its supposed to.
What can i do to fix the problem?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean that you can't use `aquaterm` in gnuplot at all, or you can't use it with `octave`?

Comment: i can't use it with Octave or GNUPlot. There are no errors shown. Aquaterm simply does not start!

Comment: I see.  I don't know how to fix aquaterm, but I do know how you can change your default terminal to something else (`x11` or `wxt`).  would that be acceptable?

Comment: To change the default variable, use the `GNUTERM` environment variable -- alternatively, you can put startup code in a file `.gnuplot` in your home directory (see `help startup` and `help env`).